Reformulate an algorithm as a sequence of standard matrix operations
Consider the following code snippet
void f(double *B, double *C, double *X, size_t nrows, size_t ncols) {
size_t slice = sqrt(ncols);
for (size_t r = 0; r < nrows; ++r) { 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < slice; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < slice; ++j) {        
            size_t rij = r*ncols + i*slice + j;
            X[rij] = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < slice; ++k) {
                size_t rjk = r*ncols + j*slice + k; 
                size_t rik = r*ncols + i*slice + k;
                X[rij] += B[rjk] * C[rik];
            }
        }
    }
}

which takes two matrices $B$ and $C$, both of size nrows $\times$ ncols and it produces another matrix $X$ of the same dimensions. Each row $r$ of $X$, $X^r$ is calculated as a kind of "product" of $B^r$ and $C^r$, in the following sense. Both $B^r$ and $C^r$ are considered as square matrices, $B^r \times (C^r)^T$ is calculated accordingly, then the result is flattened back to a row. The input/output matrices are tall, that is $\text{nrows} \approx \text{slice}^3$.
Question: How can these steps be reformulated as standard matrix operations between $B$ and $C$?
Background: I have to optimize this function and my first attempt would be to use a standard linear algebra package.
